# Are there other ways to deconstruct option types in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ml, code-readability

OCaml's option type is really useful in cases where you have functions that might not return anything. But when I use this in many places, I find it cumbersome to handle the `Some` case and the `None` case all the time in a `match ... with`.

For example,

```
let env2 = List.map (fun ((it,ie),v,t) ->
  match t with
  | Some t -> (v,t)
  | None   ->
    begin
      match it with
      | Some it -> (v,it)
      | None    -> failwith "Cannot infer local vars"
    end) ls_res in
```

Are there any other ways to deconstruct the option type in a concise manner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simple cases, you can match several things at once:

```
match t, it with
| Some t, _ -> (v, t)
| None, Some it -> (v, it)
| None, None -> failwith "Cannot infer local vars"
```

This is something I do all the time. I'm told the compiler is good with this construct (it doesn't actually generate an extra pair).

Comment: +1 I was told too that the compiler was good with this construct, but one day I looked at the assembly (I could have looked at the lambda-code, but I already knew one assembly language so that was actually less work for me) and I was disappointed. Impressive optimizations lie next to what look like forgotten obvious cases. In the case at hand, two calls to `caml_alloc2` should not be there (but are): http://pastebin.com/EfFsxhCQ

Comment: That's a drag, but I still like the clarity of this kind of match for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, there are a variety of things you could write to help deal with these. For this pattern, I'd suggest writing something like the following:

```
let or_else opt1 opt2 = match opt1 with 
  | Some _ -> opt1
  | None -> opt2
```

And then restructuring your code as:

```
let env2 = List.map (fun ((it,ie),v,t) ->
  match (or_else opt1 opt2) with
  | Some t -> (v,t)
  | None   -> failwith "Cannot infer local vars") ls_res in
```

If you've got more than this number of options, then you can fold `or_else` over them in a list:

```
let a = [None; None; Some 1; Some 2;];;
List.fold a ~init:None ~f:or_else;;
```

Comment: I suppose it's possible it might not be, but I can't see why. Jane Street's Core library defines it in their own `Option` class as `first_some`, so it's in a standard library, although I find `or_else` more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

- The option monad (aka. maybe monad). Note that `Just` in Haskell is `Some` in OCaml and `Nothing` in Haskell is `None` in OCaml. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type#The_option_monad
- Higher-order functions: `default : 'a -> 'a option -> 'a`, `map_option : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a option -> 'b option`, `or_else` as in another answer, `map_some : ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, `concat_some : 'a option list -> 'a list` etc. My names might not be standard.
- If you're in for a trouble, `unsome : 'a option -> 'a`, `let unsome = function Some a -> a | None -> raise Not_found`. Actually, this is useful if you have higher-order functions to deal with the pervasive `Not_found` exception.